# Analytic and bounded in a region with two holes is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $p,q\in\mathbb{C}, p\neq q$ and $G = \mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{p,q\right\}$ and
$f: G\to \mathbb{C}$ analytic and bounded. Show that $f$ is constant.

Hi. How could I start from this problem? I suspect that with Cauchy's modification ...

actualization.

$\lim_{z\to p}|(z-p)|f(z)|\leq \lim_{z\to p} |(z-p)|M=0$ because $f$ is bounded

therefore $p$ removable singularity, analogous $q$.

thefore exists $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ analytic and bounded. By Liouville theorem, $g$ is constant then $f$ is constant. Thanks to José Carlos Santos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem), you can extend $f$ to an entire function $F$, which will still be bounded. Therefore, $F$ is constant (by Liouville's theorem) and so, in particular, $f$ itself is constant.

Comment: that theorem is this?
$p$ removable singularity iff $\lim_{z\to p}(z-p)f(z)=0$?

Comment: I have added a link to my answer.

Comment: I write the solution in the post.